# Summation of all the distances from a random point in a circle to the points on the circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

Suppose we have a circle $C$ with radius $r$ and a random point in that circle called $P$. Now if we draw lines from the point $P$ to every points on the circumference of the circle $C$ what will be summation of all the distances? My intuition is it will be  $\pi r^2$ as all the lines will eventually fill the whole circle thus adding them will result the area of the circle. And will this hold for higher dimensions as well?

Comment: Since the number of lines is uncountably infinite, the sum of their lengths will be infinite.  So you may need to adapt your idea

Comment: You are asking for the **sum** of all distances but ${\pi}r^2$ has units of area not length.

Comment: @Henry it's just an idea. I maybe wrong.

Comment: @Sam Yes you are right. But as the lines don't have any width, adding up the lengths must give the area?

Comment: No, only if they had width would they give area. The sum of lengths cannot be the area. The sum of smaller areas can give area.

Comment: You are multiplying 0 by infinity. Actually you could use the result of $\pi r^2$ as a definition to this sum.

Comment: @KronoFaze you're right. In polar coordinates, where the pole is located in that random point, it is obvious that the sum of the segments from the point to every point on the circumference is an integral which gives the area of the circle.

Comment: @user376343 I assumed it but have no proof tho. Do you have any mathematical proof for this?

Comment: I was thinking of https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Indivisibles,_method_of . This is an excellent propedeutics to definite integral.

Comment: @user376343 Thanks